# Relation between Machine code and Von Neumann architecture

Tags: computer-architecture, computation-models

Since machine language executes instructions on ALU, CPU register and memory, is correct say that **machine code abstract the Von Neumann model**?

If exists, semantically, what is the relation between machine code and Von Neumann architecture?

Comment: I'd say it's esaxtly the other way around - the von Neumann architecture is the abstract model of machine code.

Comment: @ThreeFx So how you would (help me to) construct the following phrase: "We abstracted Von Neumann architecture to machine code, then to Assembly, then to high-level languages and beyond"

Comment: @ThreeFx That's not the case, either. You can perfectly well have a machine code for a machine that doesn't employ the von Neumann architecture (e.g., a machine with separate program and data memories). The von Neumann architecture can't be an abstraction of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking whether machine code abstracts the von Neumann model is a category error – it's a statement that doesn't type-check. The von Neumann model is essentially a system architecture: it's a way of designing computers. Machine code is a sequence of instructions: a way of telling a computer what to do. Those are two completely different things.

Machine code arguably doesn't abstract anything. It's the most concrete, specific thing there is: it runs on only one specific kind of CPU (or perhaps a family of very closely related ones).

Comment: Oh okay. My purpose (mentioned on above comment) with this question was to construct a phrase like: "We abstracted Von Neumann architecture to machine code, then to Assembly, then to high-level languages and beyond". So it's categorically wrong make this relation?

Comment: A machine code isn't an abstraction of the architecture: it's a set of instructions for the architecture. Beyond that, your statement looks fine. (By the way, "categorically wrong" means "absolutely, unarguably wrong"; I think you just mean that it's a category error, i.e., something that doesn't type-check.)

Comment: @AlexandreThebaldi Not all things in the world can be ordered linearly. You wouldn't say "Mammals are an abstraction of apples", for instance.

Comment: @Raphael Actually I'm not ordering all things in the world, just trying to create a timeline with origins of imperative languages, FYI.

Comment: @AlexandreThebaldi What do you need abstraction relations for a timeline, then?